# How to enable mysqli support when installing vtiger 6.2.0 on windows 8.1?

Tags: php, mysqli, vtiger

Hope you can help.
I'm trying to install vtiger 6.2.0 on windows 8.1 - during the installation wizard there is the part with the required values testing.

In this part everything is set to "yes" except mysqli support that appear as "no" under the present value.

In the PHP.ini in C:\Program Files (x86)\vtigerCRM620\php under Dynamic Extensions the line extension=php_mysqli.dll is without ; before it.

in the PHP.ini in C:\Program Files (x86)\vtigerCRM620\apache\htdocs\vtigerCRM\pkg\php under Dynamic Extensions there is no extension=php_mysqli.dll
so I added it to the end of the column.

Still the mysqli support appears as "no" under the present value.

By the way - I don't have a section marked [PHP_MYSQLI] in my PHP.ini files - the only place that have something to do with php_mysqli.dll is in the ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ; section.
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

what should I do?

By the way (2) - the Required Value of PHP Version is 5.5.0 and the Present Value is 5.3.10 (this is the php that comes with the vtiger installation EXE file).
I wonder if 5.5.0 is the required value of PHP - why the exe install 5.3.10?

Thanks for your help!
Ram

Comment: Try to restart Apache after enabling `extension=php_mysqli.dll` line, in `php.ini` files. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the absolute path, e.g., `extension_dir="C:/php/ext"` or `extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\vtigerCRM620\php\ext"` and restart **Apache** (*vtigercrmApache600* from **Windows Services**).

Answer (score 0):

> First create a test.php and Check mysqli support enable/disable by-

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?> //![enter image description here][1] localhost/test.php
```

[image: mysqli]

> If u did not get mysqli property than recheck/install mysqli extension=php_mysqli.dll extention in //php.ini and enable the mysqli extention and  reload/restart apache server.Hope it help for you.